# Mismatch in Histogram.

Tags: matlab, plot, statistics, histogram

I am trying to plot the histogram from the attached datasets in excel files. I have 2 questions (Q.2 is more important). The related csv files can be accessed from this link: 
[CSV files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14fiRFpL74AhBUwiYLuV0nMG5xJ6RmPN1?usp=sharing)

1.Why the two histograms are different though exact same bins and bin sizes are used.

```
aa = xlsread('LF_NPV_Branch_Run.csv','C2:C828');
bb = xlsread('RES_Cob.csv','A1:CV827');
cc = aa*ones(1,100);
dev=bb-cc;
err_a=dev';

nbins = 20;
bound_n=min([floor(min(min(err_a))/10)*10,-10])
bound_p=max([ceil(max(max(err_a))/10)*10,10])
bins = linspace(bound_n,bound_p,nbins)

hist(err_a, bins)

figure(2)
hist(err_a(:), bins)
```

2.For figure 2, though the number for the tallest bin shows ~38000, but when I calculate the number using the bin on the center (zero) the number of points should be 63039 (which is more than the limit on the Y axis), not ~38000. What is the reason of this apparent mismatch?

```
val = dev(dev > bins(10) & dev < bins(11));
size(val)
```

Answer (score 1):

*Normally, if you have multiple questions, you should ask them seperately, but I can see that these two questions are closely related.*

If you read [MATLAB's documentation for `hist(x,xbins)`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html):

> If xbins is a vector of evenly spaced values, then hist uses the values as the bin centers.

The bin edges for the bin centred at `bin(10)` are actually

```
lower=(bins(9)+bins(10))/2
upper=(bins(10)+bins(11))/2
```

Therefore, to answer your Q2, you should find the result of the following matches the bin size shown in figure:

```
val = dev(dev > lower & dev <= upper);
size(val)
```

If you want `bins` to be the edges, you should use `histogram(err_a(:), bins)`. See [Specify Bin Edges of Histogram](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram.html#buhzt18-1).

---

Q1:

`err_a` is a 100x827 matrix; `err_a(:)` makes it a 82700x1 column vector.

`hist(m, bins)` returns a bin for every column in `m` for each bin centre specified in `bins`. In your case, `err_a` has 827 columns. For each bin centre, `hist(err_a, bins)` gives 827 results and that is why there is a cluster of columns for every bin centre. `hist(err_a(:), bins)` on the other hand only gives 1 result per bin centre.